Rigid body constraint
While going through the rigid body constraint, I encountered the following statement:

For two rigid bodies to remain in contact, the relative velocity of the contact points on both the bodies along the common normal must be zero.

Can someone explain the reasoning behind this statement to me, preferably with an example that I can feel?

Suppose two things that started out at the same point had different velocities. That is, they travel at different speeds or directions. Would they separate?

@mmesser314 But the negation of the given statement doesn't imply motion at different velocities, just that they're non-zero - why can't the contact points move at identical, constant, non-zero velocities? Every constant velocity is fundamentally indistinguishable from zero velocity - any scenario with an observation of zero velocity can be turned into one with non-zero velocity simply by changing the reference frame.

I think this is just a vocabulary problem. They meant the velocity relative to each other must be $0$. That is the same thing as each having the same velocity.

The "common normal" direction is the one perpendicular to the contact surface. Positive relative velocity along this direction means the surfaces are getting farther apart, while negative relative velocity in this direction means the surfaces are getting closer together. Two rigid bodies in contact cannot possibly get any closer to one another (or else they'd be occupying the same space), and if they get any farther apart, they will no longer be in contact. For two rigid bodies touching one another to remain touching one another, the contact points can't move any closer or farther apart - the relative velocity of those points along the common normal direction must be zero.

Look at this figure

Two balls  are coiled, the connection line  between the center of masses is the normal vector $~\vec n~$
starting with this equation
$$\vec R_{c1}+r_1\,\hat n-(\vec R_{c2}+r_2\,\hat n)=0$$
multiply with $~\hat n^T~$
$$\hat n^T\left(\vec R_{c1}+r_1\,\hat n-(\vec R_{c2}+r_2\,\hat n)\right)=0\quad, \hat n^T\,\hat n=1\\
\hat n^T\left(\vec R_{c1}-\vec R_{c2}\right)+r_1-r_2=0$$
thus the time derivative is:
$$\hat n^T\left(\vec{\dot{R}_{c1}}-\vec{\dot{R}_{c2}}\right)=0$$

For two rigid bodies to remain in contact, the velocity of the contact points on both the bodies along the common normal must be zero.


Consider a wheel in contact with a road and resolve the velocity vectors of particles near the contact along the contact plane and along the contact normal (vertical for the road).
Along the plane of the contact, there can be some relative velocity of the parts as they slip past each other.
But along the contact normal any relative velocity components mean that two objects are either approaching each other or distancing from each other.
The first case, cannot happen as the two objects cannot interpenetrate, and the second option means the contact isn't maintained and the objects fly apart.
The only option for contact modeling is when the relative velocity is zero along the contact normal in order to maintain the contact over time.
